# Cannot do multipart upload to S3 bucket with SSE-KMS encryption (using .NET SDK)

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I can successfully send the `InitiateMultipartUploadRequest` and get `InitiateMultipartUploadResponse` back, but then get `Access Denied` error when sending the 1st `UploadPartRequest`.

Note that all of the below cases upload the document successfully:

1. Exactly the same code (i.e. using multipart upload), but to a different bucket that uses SSE-S3 encryption.
2. Using low-level API and uploading the document in one go, i.e. creating `PutObjectRequest` and then calling `amazonS3Client.PutObjectAsync(putObjectRequest)`.
3. Using high-level API `TransferUtility` class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the encryption key was not forwarded in the call properly.